# HTMLCLEANER handle Spanish characters

Tags: java, html, htmlcleaner

I am using HtmlCleaner library in order to parse/convert HTML files in java.

It seems that is not able to handle Spanish characters like 'ÁáÉéÍíÑñÓóÚúÜü'

Is there any property which I can set in HtmlCleaner for handling this or any other solution? Here's the code I'm using to invoke it:

```
CleanerProperties props = new CleanerProperties();
props.setRecognizeUnicodeChars(true);
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C:\\example.html");
TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(file);
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the encoding to use UTF-8?

Comment: I'm using UTF-8 when writing to a file. 

`new PrettyHtmlSerializer(props).writeToFile(tagNode, filePath, "utf-8");`

Comment: But is the HTML file actually encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: Yes.
The file was saved as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: How's it being read back? Where do you actually see the errors? Can you verify that HtmlCleaner is actually reading the file as UTF-8?

Comment: @Rup How can i verify that the HtmlCleaner is actually reading the file as UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HtmlCleaner uses the default character set read from the JVM unless specified. On Windows this will be Cp1512 not UTF-8, which is probably where it's going wrong.

You can either

- specify `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` on your JVM start line
- use the `HtmlCleaner.clean()` overload that accepts a character set

  ```
  TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(file, "UTF-8");
  ```

  (if you've got Google Guava in the project you can use `Charsets.UTF_8` for the constant)
- use the `HtmlCleaner.clean()` overload that accepts an InputStreamReader which you've already constructed with the correct character set.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `UTF-8` to `UTF-16`.

It will support maximum number of characters.

Comment: But they're just encodings - that won't change the number of characters that's supported. This might help if HtmlCleaner is reading the file with the wrong encoding and UTF-16 is generated with a BOM that it detects correctly, but I doubt it would.

Comment: @Azhar can you explain, in your own words, why you think UTF-16 has more characters than UTF-8, and where you got the idea from?

Comment: @MrLister.. When i started coding my first HTML.. I had an issue with the Supporting characters ... So i had my senior to help me out :).. He told me UTF-16 will support more characters .. Correct me if me or my senior is wrong..

Comment: @Azhar Your senior was wrong. UTF-8 supports exactly the same character set as UTF-16: all Unicode codepoints from U+0000 to U+10FFFD. (An early draft of UTF-8 provided for even more characters, but they scrapped that idea in favour of compatibility with the UTF-16 range.)