# Java HtmlCleaner: Does not handle extended ascii characters

Tags: java, ascii, extended-ascii, htmlcleaner

I'm using HTMLCleaner to clean an HTML file which has characters like '€' (ascii decimal 128), 'TM' (ascii decimal 153), etc. That is, **chars from the ASCII extended table**.

HTMLCleaner cannot handle those chars and replaces them by character '?' (ascii decimal 63).

Is there any flag I can set in HTMLCleaner in order to process those chars?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
The variable "encoding" is "iso-8859-1", just like the source file encoding.

```
    try {
        System.out.print("Parsing and cleaning:" + fileStr);
        URL url = new File(this.fileStr).toURI().toURL();
        // create an instance of HtmlCleaner
        HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
        // default properties
        CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
        // do parsing
        TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(url);
        // serialize to XML file
        new PrettyXmlSerializer(props).writeToFile(tagNode, fileStr,
                encoding);
        System.out.println("Output: " + fileStr);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've just figured this out. The line:

```
TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(url);
```

Shoube be replaced by:

```
TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(url, encoding);
```

Where 'encoding' is the string representation of the charset of the source url.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299651/htmlcleaner-handle-spanish-characters

Comment: Yes, it was a similar problem, I checked that question but I didn't realize that it was an encoding problem. Thank you, you really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try setting the `charset`?

Comment: Yes, as you can see above.
The generated HTML file has the same encoding as the source file.

Comment: I'd only set the charset in: `new PrettyXmlSerializer(props).writeToFile(tagNode, fileStr,
                encoding);` but I missed the `TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(url, encoding);`.
Now it works, thank you.